# "Unable to open file for reading" attaching PDF from storage to mailable

Tags: php, laravel

hello i have a problem right now

I am doing an "auto-attach PDF to the email page". how it works is that there is an email button in each row that when clicked, the user will be redirected to the page that automatically attaches the PDF that is stored in the storage folder according to the ID. i tried to diedump the PDF and it shows the contents of the PDF file in gibberish, which i assume is normal if doing diedump on PDF files. however, I keep getting the error "unable to open file for reading". here is my code:

Controller:

```
  public function sendToCompany(Request $request){

    $filename = request('attachedLetter');
    $letter = \Storage::get('public/coverLetter/'.$filename);


    $data = array(
        'email' => request('company_email'),
        'subject' => request('email_subject'),
        'message' => request('email_message'),
        'attachedLetter' => $letter
    );


        \Mail::to($data['email'])->send(new SendEmailToCompany($data['subject'], $data['message'], $data['attachedLetter']));
}
```

Mailable:

```
public $content;

// public $attach;

/**
 * Create a new message instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($subject, $content, $files)
{
    $this->subject = $subject;
    $this->content = $content;
    $this->attach = $files;
}

/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    $file = $this->attach;
    dd($file);
    return $this->markdown('email.emailToCompany')->attach($file);

}
```

any help will be greatly appreciated. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `attach` method expects a file path, not the content of a file. If you want to attach a file from storage you can use `attachFromStorage`. If you want to attach raw data (file contents) you can attempt to use the `attachData` method.

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Mail - Writing Mailables - Attachments](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mail#attachments)

You can pass the same path you are passing to `Storage::get` to the `attachFromStorage` method:

```
$path = 'public/coverLetter/'. $filename;

... SendEmailToCompany($data['subject'], $data['message'], $path) ...
```

then in the mailable you can try:

```
return $this->markdown('email.emailToCompany')->attachFromStorage($this->attach);
```

Comment: i've tried using storage_path() which if I diedump in the mailable, it shows the path but the "Unable to open file for reading" error still persist

Comment: I got 
"/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/newmanagementsystem/storage/coverLetter/LetterOffer_1.pdf"

Comment: there is a method specifically for attaching files from the storage system, why wouldn't you use that?  .. that string you have there isn't going to be the same file as you were asking from `Storage::get`, it is missing the 'public' part and also doesn't have 'app' in it ... but you tell me if you think that file path you have there exists

Comment: is it possible to do "this->attachFromStorage" in the construct function in the mailable? because i'm passing the file name from the HTML file to the controller, which in the last parameter of the Mail:to, it passes the filename to the mailable file

Comment: just pass the path, the same exact path you are passing to `Storage::get`, change `attach` to `attachFromStorage` and pass it that path ... if you look at the example in the docs it is even using a pdf